# MS Access runtime 2010 /2013 OutputTo PDF issue

Tags: ms-access, pdf, runtime

MS Access runtime 2010 (v14) /2013 (v15) OutputTo PDF issue

I am testing Access Runtime 2010/2013 using OutputTo PDF but have these issues:-

[image: screen capture]

PS: the same procedures when run using Access 2010 Full version creates the required PDF file from the report.

Also, I tried commenting the OutputTo line and manually clicking on the "PDF or XPS" button but nothing happens; no errors.

While a dialog says "Now outputting 'report_Name' to the file "Output_File_Path.pdf"

**Microsoft Access can't save the output data to the file  you've selected**

**The File may be open. If so, close it....**

I have verified the path and security permissions.

Comment: I added your screenshot.  It may help to show us the code which tries to create the PDF.  If the code is lengthy, please simplify it to only the minimum need to reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks.. I was really struggling to upload an image.. 

The actual code is common/usual way:
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "CXXX", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", "D:\Build\OACCESS0.pdf", False, "", 0, 0

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the file `UTILITY.ACCDA` from your

`Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\ACCWIZ`

folder to

`Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\`

folder.